# Creating a custom "Map Tile Layer" for HERE-Maps

Tags: here-api

Currently I´m using the pre-defined TileLayer "normal.day.grey" but there are still colors which have to be changed. I also checked for other TileLayers which are provided by the Map Tile API but I´m not able to meet the requirements.

Currently specific buildings are colored red and different environments in a green and grey tint. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB52w.png)

The requirements are:

1. Streets and buildings: white-color
2. Environment should be in a light-grey-color

I want to achieve the same style as in the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs6EI.png)

[Picture is from the styling wizard from Google-Maps ("Map-Style: Silver")]

Is there some way to customize the map?
I have already spent a lot of time to research for this topic but it seems there is no way than using the predefined Tile-Layers.

Applying the style to the map:

```
function setBaseLayer(map, platform){
  var mapTileService = platform.getMapTileService({
  type: 'base'
});
  var parameters = {};
  var tileLayer = mapTileService.createTileLayer(
    'maptile',
    'normal.day.grey',
    256,
    'png8',
    parameters
);
map.setBaseLayer(tileLayer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the map tiles are just predefined styles offered. But you can choose nxt to the schema also a different tile type. I think this one comes pretty close:

https://4.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/mapnopttile/b833b72c5f/reduced.day/14/8586/5547/256/png?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy&lg=ENG&lg2=ENG

Here you can find an extended example for trying out different variants:

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/mrs_options

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer!

The mentioned schema could fit my requirements.


Yours sincerely,

Lucas Kaltenbrunner

Comment: The question was answered a long time ago but this might be a new part for the solution. I found the following link: https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/ and was wondering if this tool could be used to solve my custom-style question. If so how can I use the downloaded style with my map?